# NSWindowController showWindow: flashes the window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So I'm trying to open a new NSWindow like so:

```
NSWindowController *winCon = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"];
[winCon showWindow:self];
```

When I do this, the new window flashes on the screen, as in it appears and then quickly disappears. I know that I have my window correctly referenced in IB and everything. It's like it wants to show the window, but then it gets deallocated or something weird almost immediately. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, the name of the initializer isn't `-initWithNibName:`, but `-initWithWindowNibName:`.

Second, and this is true if you're using ARC, your window goes foom because you don't have a strong reference for your instance of `NSWindowController`. When the method ends, so does your reference.

If, say, you were to do this instead in your application delegate interface:

```
@property(strong) NSWindowController *winCon;
```

And synthesized it in your implementation file:

```
@synthesize winCon;
```

Then you could set up like this:

```
self.winCon = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"];
[self.winCon showWindow:self];
```

Now your window won't disappear. The window controller will be released when the application closes.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I figured it has to do with something like that, but I didn't know how to fix it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Probably one of the best explanations I have heard. Very good example on how ARC works  when you don't property reference your variables... Thank you!

Comment: If you want to open several windows, you could add the individual NSWindowController instances to an NSMutableArray, which should first be declared as a property of your app delegate. Don't forget to instantiate the array first (like I did), using alloc-init or new.

Comment: As a slight modification, I could also keep the reference in a global static static NSMutableArray* WindowList. This seems to work when you open multiple instances of the same window, but why doesn't this work, when I instead make the NSMutableArray* WindowList a static member ('Class Variable' in cocoa) (of my WindowDelegate class)? It should still be in memory.

An even more urgent question. When the user closes the window. How do I make sure that the memory is disposed off? Since I still hold a reference to the window. Somehow garbage collections really is a pain to work with.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary might be a good choice for small app with a few windows, with better referring experience