# NSPanel with NSWindowController shows up in xcode but not in archived app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindowcontroller, nspanel

I have the problem, that my `PreferencePanel` only shows up if I launch it from Xcode in release and debug mode. But if I start the archived .app of my application, nothing happens if I click my `Preferences` button. If launched from Xcode, if I open the pref panel, close it and wait a few seconds and try that command again also nothing happens, the panel doesn't show up. I'm using a `NSWindowController` class, called "PreferenceController" and load a nib file in the `-(id)init` method with `return [super initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];`. The File Owner of the xib is set to "`PreferenceController`" and the window property is connected with the panel in the xib.

In my AppController I have an method `-(IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender` to open the panel.

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {
    PreferenceController *_preferenceController;
}

…

- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender
{
    if (!_preferenceController) {
        _preferenceController = [[PreferenceController alloc] init];
    }

    [_preferenceController showWindow:self];
}
```

The `AppController` is instantiated in the `mainMenu.xib`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618382/nswindowcontroller-showwindow-flashes-the-window

Comment: I tried that, no changes. With and without ARC.

Comment: I found out, what's the problem. I developed a NSStatusItem only app and the panel option HideOnDeactivate was set to ON. If I now open the Panel it looses automatically the focus and is gone. Thanks for helping.

Comment: ok, i have to wait 7 hours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, what's the problem. I developed a NSStatusItem only app and the panel option HideOnDeactivate was set to ON. If I now open the Panel it looses automatically the focus and is gone. Thanks for helping.